# Is every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}_{\ell}$ separable?

Tags: general-topology

Here $\mathbb{R}_{\ell}$ denotes $\mathbb{R}$ with the lower limit topology. I can show that $\mathbb{R}_{\ell}$ is separable. But I was neither able to prove the above statement nor find a counterexample...

Comment: lower limit topology?

Comment: The topology on the real line generated by the basis elements of the form $[a,b)$ where $a<b$.

Comment: Abelian, thank you.

Comment: @WlodAA It's the term Munkres uses in his text for "Sorgenfrey line". I say, let's keep the latter name in honour and call this space $\Bbb S$ again.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, thank you! Indeed, the name "lower limit topology" makes no sense to me. Also, I feel like you, that it's nice when our terminology reflects human history, it's nice to have a historic bond with the past.

Comment: @WlodAA The name Munkres uses reflect the idea that continuity in this topology can be studied via limits from the right, instead of from two sides.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I had this in the back of my mind but it's still not such a great name. A name should reflect a notion directly. Indirect names are risky, may lead to conflicts. A direct name would be something like "right neigborhoods topology".

Answer (score 4):

In fact any subset of $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ is separable. This follows directly from more advanced general theory (the space is monotonically normal and for such a space $X$, $hd(X)=d(X)$ and $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ is separable).

But a direct proof of this is not hard in this case: let $X$ be any subspace of $\mathbb{R}_\ell$. For all rationals $p < q$ such that $X \cap (p,q) \neq \emptyset$ pick a witness $y_{p,q} \in X \cap (p,q)$ (countable choice required). Also, for all rational $r$ such that $X \cap (-\infty,r)$ has a maximum (in the usual order) we let $x_r \in X$ be that maximum.

Now collecting *all* these points $x_r, x_{p,q}$ together we have a countable subset of $X$, and it is dense: let $O$ be any non-empty and open in $X$ (and we're going to show that $O$ intersects $D$), so that we have $x \in X$ and some $x' > x$ with $[x,x') \cap X \subseteq O$ (definition of subspace topology).

If $(x,x') \cap X$ is empty, pick a rational $s \in (x,x')$ and note that $x$ is the maximum of $(-\infty,s) \cap X$ and so $x=x_s$ is indeed in our dense set $D$ and $O$ intersects $D$, done.

Otherwise $(x,x') \cap X$ is non-empty (say $x'' \in X$ is in it) and we find rationals $p,q$ with $x< p < x''< q < x'$ and then $p,q$ is a pair of rationals with $(p,q) \cap X \neq \emptyset$, so we already picked above some $x_{p,q}$ in this intersection and $x_{p,q} \in D \cap [x,x') \subseteq O$ so $D$ intersects $O$ again, done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}_\ell$. For $p,q\in \mathbb{Q}$ pick, if possible, any $s\in [p,q)\cap S$ and let $D$ be a set of all such $s$'es. $D$ is clearly countable.

Is $D$ dense in $S$? Not quite, but close: Let's choose any $s_0\in S$ and consider interval $[s_0,s_0+\alpha)$ for $\alpha>0$. There are two possibilities:

$1^o$ For every $\alpha>0$ there exists $s\in (s_0,s_0+\alpha)\cap S$. Then we can take $p,q\in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $s_0<p<s<q<s_0+\alpha$ and pick $t\in D$, $t\in[p,q)$. It is possible, since $s$ could be such a $t$. It shows that $s_0$ is in the closure od $D$.

$2^o$ There exists $\alpha>0$ such that $(s_0,s_0+\alpha)\cap S = \emptyset$. Let $C = \lbrace s\in S:\ \exists \alpha>0 \ \ (s,s+\alpha)\cap S = \emptyset \rbrace$. $C$ is countable, since there is no uncountable family of pairwise disjoint open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ (since it's separable).

In conclusion $C\cup D$ is a dense and countable subset of $S$.

Comment: Where do you use the assumption that $S$ is closed? Didn't you just show that every subspace of $\mathbb R_\ell$ is separable?

Comment: Oh, right, I think I don't use that assumption. I'll change it. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,T\,$ and $\,T_\ell\,$ be the Euclidean and left topology in $\,\Bbb R\,$ respectively. Let $\,X\subseteq\Bbb R\,$ be arbitrary.

Define:

$$ L:=\{x\in X: \exists_{y_x>x}: (x;y_x)\cap X=\emptyset\} $$

Thus $\,L\,$ is the set of all isolated points in $\,(X\,\ T_\ell|X).$

Clearly,
$$ \forall_{w\ x\in X}\ (w\ne x\ \Rightarrow
         \ (w;y_w)\cap(x;y_x)=\emptyset) $$

hence $\,L\,$ is countable.

Let countable set $\,D\subseteq X\,$ be dense in $\,(X\ T|X)\,$
(Euclidean topology this time). Then obviously the countable set $\, D\cup L\,$ is dense in $\,(X\ T_\ell|X).$

***Great!***

Comment: This was what I was going to say. +1